# Update gridview after download with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter

How to update a button within a `GridView` after downloading file with `AsyncTask`.

My `MainActivity` load a `ArrayList` data with "filename, imagename and URLFile", then calls the adapter to populate the items of `GridView`:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new AdapterFiles(getApplicationContext(), mArray);
```

My adapter extends `BaseAdapter`, and, for each item, adds name, image and a button. 
If the PDF file does not exist, the application adds the button with the name of "DOWNLOAD":

```
if (!pdfFile.exists(){
    viewHolder.imageButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_download);
} else {
    viewHolder.imageButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_read);
}
```

When clicked in this button, a new `AsyncTask` class is called  to download the file:

```
viewHolder.imageButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(item, localdownload);                                            
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, I have not found a way to reload the adapter, and "re-check" that the file exists and change the button with the name "READ".

I need **re-call** my adapter `onPostExecute` of `FileDownloadTask`, but I do not know the best way to do this.

PS: I believe that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not the solution, because I don't change my `ArrayList`.

Thank you very much

Comment: make+use a listener so the MainActivity knows what to do when the AsyncTask is complete

Comment: sorry but I did not understand where I must use the listener! MainActivity or AdapterFiles? Tks

Comment: I do not know if it's the best practice, but I solved this problem by creating an interface to call MainActivity method that reload setadapter in FileDownloadTask

Comment: Thats more or less what i meant